# How to make a public variable in a method

Tags: java

I can't really find a way to do this. If I try to make a public variable it says that its an illegal modifier and that only final is allowed.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you define a variable inside a method, it will not be visible outside. Therefore the `public` keyword makes no sense.

Comment: You can assign a value to a public variable in a method, but cannot use the public keyword within a method.

Comment: What would be the point of a public variable inside a method? couldn't you just return the variable?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use public modifiers or any modifiers in the methods. The variables defined in the method are always local to that method.

For example:

```
public class MyClass{
    private String myVar1; //available within this class definition.

    public void myMehtod(){
      String myVar2; //local to myMethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: just updated my answer to call it local to that method. Thanks.